# Why doesn't phantomjs page.render capture my D3 svg?

Tags: d3.js, phantomjs

Why is my D3 visualization not captured by phantomjs? It is the only element on this page not captured and saved as png.

My oncoprintsave.js file:

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
page.viewportSize = { width: 1920, height: 1080 };
page.open('https://jonkatz2.github.io/2019/03/11/D3-oncoprint', function(status) {
    if (status !== 'success') {
        console.log('Unable to load the address!');
        phantom.exit(1);
    } else {
        window.setTimeout(function () {
            page.render('oncoprint.png');
            phantom.exit();
        }, 2000);
    }
});
```

and in my Ubuntu console I enter:

```
phantomjs oncoprintsave.js
```

This is just a representative example. I am making a shiny app in which I plan to capture some D3 visualizations as png (server-side) and include them in a rmarkdown-PDF report. I've tried r2d3::save_d3_png and got blank images, and I'm trying to troubleshoot it by calling htmlwidgets::saveWidget directly, then sending a system call to phantomjs on the resulting html page.

I suspect an error in my D3 script is causing it to fail, but I'm too new to D3 to identify it, and no errors appear if I add the --debug=true option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never solved this, but I switched to chrome and got what I want:

```
google-chrome --headless --disable-gpu --screenshot --window-size=1920,1080 https://jonkatz2.github.io/2019/03/11/D3-oncoprint
```